# how do I target specific element in a ngFor using tailwind

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the background color of the selected item. The items are looped into

tag. If an item is clicked, I want the

background colour of that specific element to change instead of the entire elements.

**Constructor**
In my constructor, I have the follow.

```
this.isSelected = false;
```

Here is the template.

```
      <div>
         <ul>
             <li *ngFor="let item of items;  let i=index">
               <span 
                (click)=onSelect(item)
                class="text-white" 
                [ngClass]="isSelected ? 'bg-blue-300': 'bg-red-300'">
               {{ item }}
               <span>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**In component.ts**

I have the following code. Here, I am trying to reset isSelected status to false when an item isn't clicked.

```
public setIcon(item: string): any {
    
        for( let myItem of this.items){
            if(myItem === item){
            return this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
            }else {
             return this.isSelected = false;
            }
        } 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one item selected at time use a variable "selectedIndex" `number` (-1 if no item selected)

```
selectedIndex:number=-1;


<span 
   (click)="selectedIndex=selectedIndex==i?-1:i"
   [ngClass]="selectedIndex==i? 'bg-blue-300': 'bg-red-300'">
</span>
```

If you want one or more item selected at time you need declare an array of booleans

```
selected:boolean[]=[];


<span 
   (click)="selected[i]=!selected[i]"
   [ngClass]="selected[i]? 'bg-blue-300': 'bg-red-300'">
</span>
```

Comment: I am planning to do something else within the click function. e.g.  when selected, fetch the id of selected item to use within my code.

Comment: pass the "index" to your function: `(click)="select(i)"` and  `select(i:number){this.selected[i]=!this.selected[i];....}` or `select(i:number){this.selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex==i?-1:i;...}`

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the question.  I have fixed it.